# how to import MBCalendarKit in your swift project

Tags: swift, mbcalendarkit

when I try to import MBCalendarKit in my project, it shows no such module error and linker command error. I tried all the solution given in stackoverflow under this topic and no success. help me.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Can you give any more information? Are you using Pods or Importing Manually?

Comment: I used pods and also tried importing manually...both did not work

Comment: Have you also included the bridging header like the installation guide suggests? Also your screenshot seems to suggest you're building the CalendarKitMB Project directly, and not just importing the files you need to your project, can you confirm either way?

Answer (score 0):

I've just imported into a test project, and using the latest version of Xcode (7.2.1) it's slightly different than the installation instructions.

1. Assuming you're using pods, install the pod and make sure to open the .xcworkspace file.
2. Next add a bridging header to the project, and import the main calendar kit file, like so

   `#import <MBCalendarKit/CalendarKit.h>`
3. Inside your `UIViewController` subclass, import `MBCalendarKit` like so:

   `import MBCalendarKit`
4. Celebrate!

Comment: Sorry... But still the error persists after pod installations and adding bridging headers...